# What driver to use with Groovy/Gradle to Connect to an Oracle Database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, groovy, gradle

Here's the drivers I'm getting from my build.gradle file:

```
compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1102-jdbc41'
compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31'
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.1'
compile 'com.oracle:ojdbc14:10.2.0.4.0'
```

PostgreSQL and MySQL work just fine, but when I try the same thing with Oracle it gives me the error(with my connection details in the brackets):

```
Caught: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@[host]:[port]/[SID]
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@[host]:[port]/[SID]
at OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.groovy:8)
at orCheck.run(orCheck.groovy:1)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Is the driver I'm getting from Maven, `com.oracle:ojdbc14:10.2.0.4.0` even the right one? It seems like it hasn't been updated in a while, but there don't seem to be any other Oracle drivers in the repository.

Comment: As far as I know there's the driver You're looking for isn't present in maven repo due to licensing. Search for drivers here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opal's comment pointed me in the right direction. I was able to get gradle to accept it by downloading the ojdbc7.jar, putting it in a `lib` directory for my project and setting up a `flatDir` repository.

```
repositories {
  flatDir(dir: 'libs', name: 'Local libs')
}

dependencies {
  compile name: 'ojdbc7'
}
```